# Trying to incorporate many conditions into one formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested

so I tried building the following massive formula:

```
=IF(AND(S284<>"",R284<>"",A284<>B284),INDEX(RATE, MATCH($A284,BID_NO,0), MATCH($R284,RATES,0)),IF(AND(S284<>"'',R284="",A284<>B284),INDEX(SHIFT_INFO, MATCH($A284,SHIFT_BID,0), MATCH(L$4,SHIFT_HEADER,0)),IF(AND(S284="",R284<>"",INDEX(SHIFT_INFO, MATCH($B284,SHIFT_BID,0), MATCH(L$4,SHIFT_HEADER,0)) <> INDEX(SHIFT_INFO, MATCH($A284,SHIFT_BID,0))),INDEX(RATE, MATCH($A284,BID_NO,0), MATCH($R284,RATES,0)),IF(AND(S284="",R284="",INDEX(SHIFT_INFO, MATCH($B284,SHIFT_BID,0), MATCH(L$4,SHIFT_HEADER,0)) <> INDEX(SHIFT_INFO, MATCH($A284,SHIFT_BID,0))),INDEX(SHIFT_INFO, MATCH($A284,SHIFT_BID,0), MATCH(L$4,SHIFT_HEADER,0))),"")
```

This formula was much simpler than this before but some conditions were added that we wanted to see if it could encompass them. It attempts to encompass several scenarios on a spreadsheet regarding schedule changes. Each schedule is assigned as a bid number in column A as well as one is column B. They are always equal until someone actually changes a schedule.

The purpose of the formula is to compare the data of the bid # in column A - The new bid they are going to and the data of the bid # in column B - the old bid that they are coming off of. In this case, this particular data is rate of pay.

If the rates of pay are the same, the formula will leave the cell blank.

If they are not the same, it will give the pay rate data of the new bid so we know what the rate needs to be changed to. As I mentioned, there were some added conditions in additional columns which I am now going to list:

**Bear in mind, There are 2 tabs giving different rates of pay since employees fall into Tier 1 or Tier 2 rates depending on when they were hired. Column "R" determines which tab a lookup will pull from. If "R" is blank, it pulls info from one tab of Rates which we will call Tier 1. If "R" is NOT blank, it pulls info from a different tab of rates which we will call Tier 2.

- If column "A" is equal to column "B", then column "L" (this is the column that contains the big formula) is left blank. This condition takes precedence above all others.
- If column "A" is NOT equal to column "B", column "R" is NOT blank, and column "S" IS blank, then do a lookup of the bid # in column "A" for that bid's rate of pay and do a lookup of column "B" for that bid's rate of pay. If the rate of pay for both Lookups match, column L is left blank. If they do NOT match, do a lookup for the number in Column A and display that rate. Because "R" has a value, the lookup will yield info from Tier 2 rates.
- If column "A" is NOT equal to column "B", column "R" is NOT blank, and Column S is NOT blank, then do a lookup of the rate of the bid number in column A, even if the rate between A bid and B Bid are identical. Again, because "R" has a value, the lookup will yield info from Tier 2 rates.
- If column "A" is NOT equal to column "B", column "R" IS blank, and Column S IS blank, then do a lookup of the number in column "A" for that bid's rate of pay and do a lookup of column "B" for that bid's rate of pay. If the rate of pay for both Lookups match, column "L" is left blank. If they do NOT match, do a lookup for the number in Column A and display that rate. Because "R" has NO value, the lookup will pull from the Tier 1 rates.
- If column "A" is NOT equal to column "B", column "R" IS blank, and Column S is NOT blank, then do a lookup of the rate of the bid number in column A, even if the rate between A bid and B Bid are identical. Again, because "R" has NO value, the lookup will pull from the Tier 1 rates.

Again, I tried the formula at the top to encompass all of these scenarios. I got the 255 character limit message and so I am stuck. I realize this is way past information overload, so of course if it is easier and someone is willing to help, I can attach a template of the spreadsheet so that you can actually see what is being worked with. I can also be available for instant messaging to answer questions if that helps.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!*  There's no reason that every part of the calculation needs to go into one cell... but there are many advantages to splitting it up into several cells (perhaps one for each logical "decision").  Also, this would be much easier to understand with if you shared a sample of your data, and an example of the finished calculation.  (If it's sensitive data then you can post 'fake' data as long as it's representative of the real thing.)  See [mcve] as well as [ask], plus these [great tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: "I can attach a template of the spreadsheet" <-- in order for others to test the formula, it'll be really useful..

Comment: ...well, you **can't** attach files (and we don't want anything huge anyway) but an example of the data (and nothing irrelevant) could be helpful.  (See my links above)

Comment: If you are the only one using the workbook, the suggestions for breaking up the formula can be quite beneficial, especially for debugging. Also, doing each test in a separate column can help you confirm the accuracy of your logic. I have have labeled columns Test1, Test2 etc and then my formula simply become an AND of all the columns. Fixing a bad column is easier than fixing a cell with a huge formula. If you need to "show" it to someone, you can hide the intermediate columns and show only the result.

Comment: just change the last `))),"")` to `)),"")))) `

Comment: Hi guys, unfortunately, I don't think separating into other cells is really an option. This spreadsheet has other columns pretty much doing the same thing as this column although their cell lookups are not as in depth as this one as they pull different data. Unfortunately, there really is no way for me to explain this within the character limit. I tried looking for a way to send a private message to see if I might somehow send the sheet to someone but I can't seem to find that. Can someone advise? If I am able to get help on this, I could post the solution given. I did try Phidots.